# Can not find custom definition typescript v3

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

Typescript is giving me this error when I run my webpack dev server

```
ERROR in ./src/components/allowcated-resources/AllowcatedResources.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-scheduler' in 'mypath\allowcated-resources'
 @ ./src/components/allowcated-resources/AllowcatedResources.tsx 3:0-41 77:20-28
 @ ./src/components/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ multi ./src/index.tsx
```

here is the tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "my-scheduler": ["typings/my-scheduler"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin",
        "alwaysShowRuleFailuresAsWarnings": false,
        "ignoreDefinitionFiles": true,
        "configFile": "./tslint.json",
        "suppressWhileTypeErrorsPresent": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

I have directory called 'typings' in the root and the hierarchy is 'typings/my-scheduler/index.d.ts'

index.d.ts

```
declare module 'my-scheduler' {
  // export members
  export class TimeSpan { // }
}
```

I can locate to this typing on clicking vs code import

```
import { TimeSpan } from 'my-scheduler';
```

but when I run web pack server It is giving this

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-scheduler'
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two conflicting module resolutions mechanisms, ambient external module declarations and standard module resolution based on resolution mechanisms such as `--paths` and `--moduleResolution`.

Ambient external module declarations, which can be detrimental because they pollute the global namespace of module declarations have the form

```
// it doesn't matter where this file is or what it's called, as long as TypeScript includes it

declare module 'my-scheduler' {
  export class TimeSpan {}
}
```

Such declarations are not resolved based on the location of their containing file or any other module resolution conditions. They become available for import whenever the file containing the declaration is included in TypeScript's compilation context.

The other, and preferable form is to use module resolution, such as paths are resolved just like any other module and do not pollute the global namespace of module declarations, and have the form

```
export declare class TimeSpan {}
```

Therefore, since you are using paths, you want to use the latter form, which is just a normal module

```
export declare class TimeSpan {}
```

Comment: actually the module and its exports are not my own files. these are from 3rd party library.I need to import them into my project. That's what i'm trying to do

Comment: Then remove it from `--paths`, you might also need to list it under `--include`